# Список установленных программ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.x

Как извлечь установленные программы в системе(получить список)? Для windows

Comment: работайте напрямую с os, если windows, вызывайте power shell, сохраняйте в файл, открывайте питоном, если линукс то через shell аналогично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многие установленные программы добавляют свой `Uninstall`, так можно будет найти их.

В реестре это хранится по этим путям:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

---

Думаю, [код и](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d59996d18f5edfc675f0b790aa13b4642e2e8822/uninstall_tool/main.py) под python2 пойдет (если с print разберетесь):

```
from winreg import *

UNINSTALL_PATH_LIST = [
    r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',
    r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
]

programs_dict = dict()

for path in UNINSTALL_PATH_LIST:
    with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path) as key:
        for i in range(QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
            keyname = EnumKey(key, i)
            subkey = OpenKey(key, keyname)

            try:
                subkey_dict = dict()
                for j in range(QueryInfoKey(subkey)[1]):
                    k, v = EnumValue(subkey, j)[:2]
                    subkey_dict[k] = v

                if 'DisplayName' not in subkey_dict:
                    continue

                name = subkey_dict['DisplayName'].strip()
                if not name:
                    continue

                programs_dict[name] = subkey_dict

            except WindowsError:
                pass


for number, name in enumerate(sorted(programs_dict.keys()), 1):
    subkey_dict = programs_dict[name]
    print('{}. {}:'.format(number, name))
    print('    {}: {}'.format('DisplayVersion', subkey_dict.get('DisplayVersion', '')))
    print()
```